# How to add a unit test for a new contract

Tags: smart-contract, unit-tests

I am currently on eosio v1.1 but will be upgrading to v1.2 shortly.

I am trying to create a new unit test for my contract.  The existing unittest work when I run the following:

```
cd eos/build/unittest

unit_test -t tic_tac_toe_tests

Random number generator seeded to 1535128111

Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
```

Now I want to create a new test for my contract
For example:

```
unit_test -t mycontract_tests

Random number generator seeded to 1535128123

Test setup error: no test cases matching filter or all test cases were disabled
```

Where I made the file
eos/unittests/mycontract_tests.cpp

I am guessing I need to add this file name in somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Look https://www.npmjs.com/package/eoslime. It allows you to write javascript tests for your contracts

Check out the eoslime example to get a better idea of how to write tests.
  -> example: https://github.com/LimeChain/eoslime/blob/master/example/eosio-token/usage-example.js